# How to detect what binded to some shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

I am using editor for developers: Visual Studio Code. There is some keybinding: Shift + Options + F. It reformats code.

When I press it - no code is reformatted, but I get a  `̰` symbol in the editor. What is it? How to debug what exactly catches this keybinding and do something?

It is not first problem. Yesterday I saw that shortcut for my action is F11. I press F11 and nothing happens. After that I accidently (when I was not on full-screen application) noticed that F11 shows the desktop. I realised, that I can unbind it in system prefs and that worked. But I didn't find Shift + Opts + F shortcut in system prefs.

Comment: What keyboard layout do you use?

Comment: ̰  is the 'COMBINING TILDE BELOW' (U+0330) (0xCCB0)

Comment: @MaxRied what do you mean when you say keyboard layout? Do you mean input source? I have ABC - Extended.

Comment: US English? Russian? US International?

Comment: @klanomath okay, thank you! but why it appears when I press Shift-Opts-F? How to disable this behaviour?

Comment: @maxried I think I have `English, International (Z)` (from [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794) source)

Comment: Here is [the photo](http://i.imgur.com/YAIxCjy.jpg).

Comment: Oh no! Wait =) I have russian layout =) of course. I just found some english that fits to my russian keys (~ key, ± key etc =) )

Comment: in macOS opt/alt-.../shift-opt/alt-... is not considered a (classical) short cut.... Here shift-alt-F is `Ï`